# Unable to Implement Search for Custom ListView in Android

Tags: java, android, listview

I've been trying to implement search for a ListView in my Activity, which uses a custom adapter. The List is fetched from a particular URL. This is what I've tried. The error is "The method getName() is undefined for the type String". Please help.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.saregama;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
  Activity context;
   HttpPost httppost;
   StringBuffer buffer;
   HttpResponse response;
   HttpClient httpclient;
   ProgressDialog pd;
   CustomAdapter adapter;
   ListView listProduct;
   ArrayList<String> records;
   String mname;
   Intent i;
   Intent j;
   BackTask bt;
   Intent k;
   EditText et;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   //TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 //  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
   //        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   context=this;
   records=new ArrayList<String>();
   listProduct=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.product_list);
   et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.search_movies);
   i = new Intent(this, ReportActivity.class);
   j = new Intent(this, RequestActivity.class);
   k = new Intent(this, AboutDeveloper.class);
   Intent iin= getIntent();
   Bundle b = iin.getExtras();
   if(b!=null)
   {
       mname =(String) b.getString("second_selection");

   }
   this.setTitle("All Movies - "+mname);
   adapter=new CustomAdapter(context, R.layout.list_item,R.id.pro_name, records);
   listProduct.setAdapter(adapter);
   bt=new BackTask();
   bt.execute();
   listProduct.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id){

           String sText = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pro_name)).getText().toString();
           Intent songIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SongActivity.class);
           songIntent.putExtra("movie_name", sText );
           startActivity(songIntent);

       }

   });

   et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

       @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
               int textlength = cs.length();
               ArrayList<String> records = new ArrayList<String>();
               for(String c: records){
                  if (textlength <= c.getName().length()) {
                     if (c.getName().toLowerCase().contains(cs.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        records.add(c);
                     }
                  }
               }
               listProduct.setAdapter(adapter);
         }

       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
               int after) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       }
   });

   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
       //create a LayoutTransition object       
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

       super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

       switch(item.getItemId()){
           case R.id.report:
               startActivity(i);
               break;

           case R.id.request:
               startActivity(j);
               break;

           case R.id.action_refresh:
               finish();
               startActivity(getIntent());
               break;

       //    case R.id.aboutme:
        //     startActivity(k);
          //     break;




       }
       return true;

   }

  //background process to make a request to server and list product information
   private class BackTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{  
   protected void onPreExecute(){
       super.onPreExecute();
       pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
       pd.setTitle("Retrieving data");
       pd.setMessage("Please wait.");
       pd.setCancelable(true);
       pd.setIndeterminate(true);
       pd.show();       

       }

       protected Void doInBackground(Void...params){ 

       InputStream is=null;
       String result="";
       try{

           records.clear();

           String query = URLEncoder.encode(mname, "utf-8");
       httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
          httppost= new HttpPost("http://necrecords.16mb.com/getproducts.php?password="+query);
       response=httpclient.execute(httppost);         
             HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
             is = entity.getContent();

       }catch(Exception e){

       if(pd!=null)
       pd.dismiss();  //close the dialog if error occurs 
       Log.e("ERROR",e.getMessage());

       }

       //convert response to string
       try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"utf-8"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                  sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();         
            result=sb.toString();
       }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("ERROR", "Error converting result "+e.toString());

}

       //parse json data
       try{

       JSONArray jArray =new JSONArray(result);
       for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                  String record=json_data.getString("pname")+"__"+json_data.getInt("uprice");
                  records.add(record);


          }


       }
       catch(Exception e){
       Log.e("ERROR", "Error pasting data "+e.toString());

       }

        return null;
       }   


       protected void onPostExecute(Void result){

       if(pd!=null) pd.dismiss(); //close dialog
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //notify the ListView to get new records

       }

}
}
```

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.saregama;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

int groupid;
ArrayList<String> records;
Context context;
public CustomAdapter(Context context, int vg, int id, ArrayList<String> records){
super(context,vg, id, records);
this.context=context;
groupid=vg;
this.records=records;

}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     View itemView = inflater.inflate(groupid, parent, false);
     String[] row_items=records.get(position).split("__");
     TextView textName= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pro_name);
     textName.setText(row_items[0]);
     TextView textPrice= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pro_uprice);
     textPrice.setText(row_items[1]+"$");
     return itemView;
}
}
```

Comment: Hey follow this [Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/).

Answer (score 1):

In `onTextChanged` you are creating an empty `List` of `String`s and trying to call `getName` on each of them.  As your error message indicates, `getName` is not a method on `String`, so this does not compile.

Comment: so how can I implement search to this kind of dynamic listviews?

Comment: @ShahidRoshan there are already a lot of similar questions here on SO, simply use your favorite search engine to find them ...

Comment: @ShahidRoshan, I'm not really familiar with this API, sorry.